# What is the past-the-end iterator in STL C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Any one could explain me what is the meaning of `past-the-end`. Why we call `end()` function past-the-end?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The functions `begin()` and `end()` define a ***half open range(`[begin, end)`)***, which means:
The range includes first element but excludes the last element. Hence, the name past the end.

[image]

The advantage of an half open range is:

1. It avoids special handling for empty ranges. For empty ranges, `begin()` is equal to
   `end()` .
2. It makes the end criterion simple for loops that iterate over the elements: The loops simply
   continue as long as `end()` is not reached

Comment: The illustration smells like Josuttis :)

Comment: Not just `begin()` and `end()`; generally, `[begin, end)` defines a **sequence** of values, regardless of where the iterators come from or where the values are held.

Comment: 3. The number of elements in the range is `end - begin` (for random-access iterators), not some expression with an annoying +1 in it.

Answer (score 7):

Because it doesn't point to the **last** element of a container, but to somewhere **past** the last element of a container.

If you dereference `end()` it results in **undefined behaviour**.

Answer (score 5):

Like interval in mathematics, stl uses `[begin, end)`.

That's why we could write `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)`

Comment: Yes! The first answer that doesn't talk about containers, which are not required to create sequences.

Comment: But so is `[begin,end]`; and then there also are `(a,b]`, `(a,b)`. Please elaborate, what's so special that you see in math about the `[a,b)` compared to other intervals?

Comment: @Hi-Angel [Why numbering should start at zero](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

Answer (score 3):

Literally, because it points one past the end of the array.

It is used because that element is empty, and can be iterated to, but not dereferenced.

```
int arry[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, /* end */ };
                         ^^^^^^^
                    std::end(arry) would point here.
```

Comment: Not just arrays; the `end` iterator points past the end of the target sequence, regardless of where the the iterators come from or where the values are held.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another point to the above correct answers.
This was also done to be compatible with arrays.
For example in the code below:

```
char arr[5];
strcpy(arr, "eakgl");
sort(&arr[0], &arr[5]);
```

This will work fine.

Instead if you had given :

```
sort(&arr[0], &arr[4]);
```

it would miss sorting the last character.

This also helps to represent empty containers naturally.