# In *min_element (first_index, last_index); function , why last_index is excluded for min calculations?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I expected the following program will give 0 as output but actually it is 1. Why the first element is considered and last element is not considered for min calculation?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> arr = {5,4,3,2,1,0};
    cout<<*min_element(arr.begin()+1,arr.begin()+5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Range in c++ is open-close (`[begin, end[`)...

Comment: Is that range applicable for all STL functions?

Comment: All stl methods work on the range `[first, last)`

Comment: Yes, all stl functions work that way, that allow to handle empty ranges easily.

Comment: @Jarod42, am not that familiar with empty ranges terminology, can you explain it?

Comment: @KishoreP [What is the past-the-end iterator in STL C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15252002/1332041)

Comment: Yes, it is clear now, thanks @xskxzr

Answer (score 3):

Your final iterator needs to be [one-past-the-end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15252002/1332041) to work as you expect.

i.e.

```
arr.begin()+6
```

or why not just

```
arr.end()
```

Comment: thanks for directing to past-the-end link, I want to find the min element in intermediate-range that's why I won't be using arr.end() always

Comment: can you explain what is an empty range and why it is important to handle empty range?

Comment: @KishoreP empty range is a range with no elements. Why it is important? For example  empty container. In this situation it would have `cont.begin()` == `cont.end()` and handling that is simple in any algo it would be passed to as a range. Otherwise you would have to check before calling or have additional flag passed. Which is error prone and unnecessary. And this is just one of the symptoms, there would be more.

Comment: Much appreciated @Slava :)