# The output of the last list element does not occur

Tags: c++

My task is to display the first and last elements of the list. I have iterators that point to the first and last element of a list. With their help, I am trying to implement a task. Everything works with the first element, with the last - the program crashes. What could be the problem?

```
typedef list<float>::iterator it;
it i = X.begin(); it j = X.end();
cout << "First element -->> " << *i << "\tLast element -->> ";
cout << *j << endl;
```

Comment: [iterator end reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/): Returns an iterator pointing to the **past-the-end element** in the sequence:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `begin()` and `end()` define a half open range(`[begin, end)`), which means:
The range includes first element but excludes the last element. Hence, the name past the end.

[image]

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252207/5735010) answer for `The advantage of an half open range`.

Have a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). To print the last element, try this:

```
typedef list<float>::iterator it;
it i = X.begin(); it j = X.end();
cout << "First element -->> " << *i << "\tLast element -->> ";
cout << *(j - 1) << endl;
```

Or

A better option would be [rbegin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin).

```
typedef list<float>::iterator it;
it i = X.begin(); it j = X.rbegin();
cout << "First element -->> " << *i << "\tLast element -->> ";
cout << *j << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/):

> `end` Returns an iterator pointing to the *past-the-end element* in the sequence

This element *does not exist*, so you can't access it. But it allows you to iterate nicely (using `<` for comparison, not `<=`):

```
for (it = X.begin(); it < X.end(); ++it)
    // do stuff
```