# std::views::istream with std::views::take

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I compiled the following code with g++ 12.2.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::ranges::copy(std::views::istream<int>(std::cin) | std::views::take(3), std::back_inserter(vi));
    for (auto i : vi)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Input:

```
1 2 3
4
```

Output: `1 2 3`

Why do I have to enter 4 numbers instead of 3 and discard the last one? How to solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you finish typing `1 2 3`, `views::istream<int>(std::cin) | views::take(3)` did *not* reach the end, because its iterator just points to the last element and doesn't [pass the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252002/what-is-the-past-the-end-iterator-in-stl-c).

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (for linux) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows) to terminate the input like

```
1 2 3
Ctrl + D
```